# Segmentation fault when running 'bundle exec rake'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rake, bundler

After running:

`$ bundle exec rake`

I receive this error:

```
/Users/user/Documents/Code/spree_gem/vendor/bundle/gems/json-
1.8.2/lib/json/ext/parser.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x00000000000418 
ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [x86_64darwin14.0]
```

Along with this:

```
/Users/user/Documents/Code/spree_gem/vendor/bundle/bin/rake:23
:in `<main>'
/Users/user/Documents/Code/spree_gem/vendor/bundle/bin/rake:23
:in `load'
/Users/user/Documents/Code/spree_gem/vendor/bundle/gems/rake-
10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
```

I've tried `$ gem pristine --all`. Any thoughts?

Comment: did you try your Gemfile source `http://rubygems.org`

Comment: yes, that is included in my Gemfile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same error too. Googled around and found these two posts
http://community.onemonth.com/t/install-rvm-error/1883/25
https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9444

The first post's solution fixed it for me, so for you it would be:

```
rvm get stable
rvm reinstall ruby-2.1.5
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

1. Uninstall ruby: `rvm remove 2.2.1`
2. Install ruby: `rvm install 2.2.1`
3. Reinstall rails: `sudo gem install rails`
4. Reinstall missing gems: `bundle install`
5. Update RubyGems `gem install rubygems-update`
6. Reset gems `gem pristine --all`
7. Maybe you'll have to rerun `bundle install`

Try running rails server `rails s`

Answer (score 1):

Actually, just recalling `rvm use ruby-2.2.5` fixed this for me, and is less destructive than the other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same error

But below configuration will start working for me.

```
rvm pkg install iconv
rvm pkg install openssl
rvm reinstall 2.1.5 --with-openssl-dir=~/.rvm/usr --with-iconv-dir=~/.rvm/usr
```

Also it was working whileI have made in `Gemfile` by replacing

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

this line with

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
```

Comment: Do you know the equivalent of this fix using Chruby?

Comment: Fantastic, `rvm pkg install iconv` also fails, with rvm 1.26.10 / Mac OS X 10.10.2